# How to get the position/bounds of text selected in an input field?

Tags: javascript, selection, firefox-addon-webextensions

To know the position/size/bounds of selected text in a webpage, I can usually do this:

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
```

However, window.getSelection() does not work for selections in input fields. I can get the selectionStart and selectionEnd for the input field, but these are string indexes, so they don't help.

**Is there a way to calculate the selection "bounds" accurately for input fields?**

I have no need for cross-platform solutions. This is for Firefox 52 or later, to be used in a content script of a WebExtension. Thanks!

Comment: Would the entire input element be okay or are you looking specifically for the highlighted characters in the input?

Comment: Hey Phillip, I'm looking for the highlighted (selected) characters in the input field, otherwise a simple getBoundingClientRect() would work on the element itself, I believe.

Comment: Yea, that's what I was going to suggest. Otherwise I'm not seeing a way to fetch bounds of the value of an input.